# Binding object to window textboxes in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class named `Data` with some public members: `Name`, `Age`, `Address`.

I have also window with text boxes `Name`, `Age`, `Address`.

The `Data` object can change any time.

How can I bind the `Data` object to the text boxes and follow after object changes?

I know there is `INotifyPropertyChanged` and "dependency-properties" but I do not know how to use them.

**Edit**

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _name;

  public string Name
  {
    get
    {
      return _name;
    }
    set
    {
      if (_name != value)
      {
        _name = value;
        OnPropertyChnged("Name");
      }
    }
   }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
     ProppertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
   }
}
```

XAML code:

```
xmlns:myApp="clr-namespace:MyApp"
<Window.Resources><myApp:MyData x:key = data/></WindowResources>
<TextBox><TextBox.Text><Binding Source="{StaticResource data}" Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/></TextBox.Text></TextBox>
```

---

```
class OtherClass
{
  private MyData data;
  //the window that have the binding textbox
  private MyWindow window;
  public OtherClass()
  {
    data = new MyData();
    data.Name = "new name"
    window = new MyWindow();
    window.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` should take you 5 minutes: 2 minutes google-ing & 3 minutes copy/pasting it in your code... Learning the syntax to bind your `TextBox` to an object should take even less time :)

Comment: Actually I have wpf book and I spend more than 5 min in google and I still dont get it... This is my first time with wpf and all new for me

Comment: Can you add your code for defining the StaticResource data?

Comment: Does this build, because you seem to have a couple of typo's, the a is missing in the OnPropertyChanged("Name") and there is an extra p in PropertyChangedEventHandler?

Comment: @Paulie I can't copy paste the code. I wrote the code in computer without internet conection therefore the mistakes. I added more code where I change the property and show the window with the binding textbox

Comment: Plus, your key for your static reference is missing double quotes, "data", your missing a dot in the WindowResources Closing tag.

Comment: That's a different instance of the class, the view's static resource is constructing it's own instance of the class so the one you create in OtherClass does not get used. You could get rid of the StaticResource and then set the use DataContext of the window to that instance of the class, then change your binding to <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>

Comment: I didnt know that. Thanks I change it and let you know. 
can you show me base on my code where (in window or grid or the specific textbox) to write it?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, do you mean setting the DataContext? If so you can put in your code sample above : window.DataContext = data; before showing the window.

Comment: Thanks you very much Paulie and Ing'o. I must go now so Ill try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) from MSDN explains it well.</strike>

**MSDN link is dead, adding link to a similar [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/16/someone-s-been-sitting-in-my-chair-property-changed-detection-mechanisms-in-wpf.aspx).**

When your class property is changed, your property should raise a OnPropertyChanged event with the name of the property so that the View knows to refresh it's binding.

```
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

And your textbox should have a binding such as:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

I have a ViewModelBase class which is where I have implemented my OnPropertyChandedEvent for all derived models to call:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An event for when a property has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Virtual method to call the Property Changed method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property which has changed.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget that the object holding the Data (ViewModel) must be set as the DataContext of the XAML (View).

Comment: True, I had assumed that the poster had figured that out already but I should have stated explicitly.

Comment: @Paulie Waulie I probably missing somethig. I did what you wrote and before I create and open the window I put some value in the Data.Name property and nothing show in the relevnt textbox... any idea?

Comment: It sounds like the binding is not correct on the TextBox, you could try downloading this tool : http://www.wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html, attach to your app and then press control and hover over the TextBox, this will give you a plethora of details about the control. One tab will be DataContext, if that is null then you have not set the data context for the view, otherwise check to see the value of your property in that tab. How are you setting the DataContext for the view?

Comment: @Maya Remember to monitor the Output box of Visual Studios for all DataBinding errors, they will appear there.

Comment: @Maya You mention that you put some value in the Name property. Did you just hardcode it in? I see you mention elsewhere that you create the instance of MyData in XAML, you do know that it's a seperate instance.

Comment: Where are your setting the value?

Comment: I added code the showing where I setting the value, can you check it?

@Ingó so what I need to do?

Comment: before you do `Window.Show();` do `Window.DataContext = data;` You have set your instance now as the context for the window. You then have to remove `Source="{StaticResource data}"` from the XAML code. Notice this is just one way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's the Data class implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) . Raise the event when someone change the property value on the instances of Data. Then set the proper [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) to your UI, and bind the single ui element as for example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age}"/>
```